# Batch buffer loop using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, buffer, batch

How can I create a nested conditional that allow the user to choose between buffering for an individual file or for a list of files and then carry out the buffer according to the user's choice?

```
buff_choice = input("single_file" or "List_of_files")       
if buff_choice == "single_file":
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features, fcBuffer, buff_distance)
    airport_out = input("Please provide output file name:")
    in_features = "maine_airports.shp"
    buff_distance = input("Please provide buffer distance: ")
    
if buff_choice == "List_of _files":   
    list_1 = arcpy.ListFiles()
for l in list_1:
    listBuffer = os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + ' Buffer.shp'
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features, fcBuffer, buff_distance)
    airport_out = input("Please provide output file name:")
    in_features = "maine_airports.shp"
    buff_distance = input("Please provide buffer distance: ")


import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace= "C:/Users/abdo0007/Desktop/Spatial_programming/exam/Data/Maine_2"
env.overwriteOutput= True
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    
    for fc in fcs:
airport_out = input("Please provide output file name:")
in_features = "maine_airports.shp"
buff_distance = input("Please provide buffer distance: ")
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(inputfeature, outputfeature, "bufferdist,"","","all""")
```

Comment: Why would you use a nested conditional for this?  The code you've presented isn't valid Python, and the `conditional` tag doesn't have anything to do with flow-of-control logical operators.

Comment: The question asks for a nested conditional

Comment: Yes, you're asking for a nested conditional, but it doesn't take nesting to address the task (one element list and multi-element list, as a simple if/else Boolean test). This is more of an [so]-ish Python flow of control issue.

Comment: Your indenting is all over the place and there are numerous other errors in your code.  If this is for a piece of assessment you are undertaking, you probably need to have another look at your course notes.